# Kotlin: using inheritance or generics to reuse a function for different classes

Tags: generics, inheritance, kotlin

I'm doing a simple project in Kotlin to try and learn the language a bit better, but I'm stuck on one particular problem.

The project is for a simple recipe management app, so far i just have basic objects for recipes, ingredients, and allergies, as well as objects for storing collections of them.

I have decided that I would like the option to search for a recipe by it's name variable. To do this I created a function which searches the recipe list in the recipe store, and adds results to a mutable list of recipes based on a number of conditions, which ensures the first elements of the list are the most relevant.

I was able to do this, but then decided that the other object stores should have this functionality, to allow easy searching for info about ingredients, as well as giving the option of adding a simple autocomplete function that returns relevant suggestions when entering ingredients in the recipe creation UI.

Since the search/filtering function is rather large I wanted to re-use it, given that it would be the same for each object: take a HashSet and a String, and return a filtered and sorted list e.g. given a HashSet and a String, do the search and return a List.

Where I'm struggling is making a generic function like this that can take any of the 3 types of object I want to be able to filter, and returns a list of that object.

I initially made a Utils class, and in it tried making the function take generics:

```
fun <T> sortObjectsBySearchRelevance(search: String, set: Set<T>): List<T> {
  var orderedList = mutableListOf<T>()

  set.forEach{
    if(it.name == search) orderedList.add(it)
  }

  return orderedList
}
```

(the actual filtering/searching code is a lot bigger with plenty of if else and forEach statements, but for simplicity i have just included the exact match case since the sorting functionality isn't important here)

I realized when doing this that accessing the name parameter of object T was not possible.

I then created a class "SearchableObject" which always has a name parameter, and set the other classes to extend to extend it, so I could set the parameter type of the sortObjectsBySearchRelevance to be SearchableObject, allowing the function to access the name variable:

```
open class SearchableObject (open var name: String){


}
```

```
import common.SearchableObject

class Allergy(override var name: String = "Allery name not given") : SearchableObject(name){
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Allergy(name='$name')"
    }

}
```

The re-usable search function was then:

```
fun sortObjectsBySearchRelevance(search: String, set: Set<SearchableObject>): List<SearchableObject> {
  var orderedList = mutableListOf<SearchableObject>()

  set.forEach{
    if(it.name == search) orderedList.add(it)
  }

  return orderedList
}
```

However in the AllergyStoreImpl class, the search method looks like this:

```
override fun autoSuggest(search: String): List<Allergy> {

        val orderedList = utils.sortObjectsBySearchRelevance(search, allergies)
        var orderedAllergyList = mutableListOf<Allergy>()
        orderedList.forEach { if(it is Allergy) orderedAllergyList.add(it) }
        return orderedAllergyList
```

I had to add some extra lines of code to verify that every element of the list is an allergy and then add it to a new list, which I was then able to return.

Is there an easier or more elegant way to do this?

I want to have the Utils class, available to other classes, which contains an publicly available function. The function takes a string and a set of objects, the set will either be all Recipe objects, all Ingredient objects, or all Allergy objects. The function must then be able to perform operations on the objects in the set (by using their 'name' parameter, which all of them will have), and then returns a list of that type of object.

e.g. takes set of recipes and string, returns ordered list of recipes.

Comment: hmmm... I wonder whether you make things more complicated than easier... If you have a set of `T` then just do: `yourSet.filter { it.name == search }` which will automatically return you a new list with the filtered items... I wouldn't introduce `SearchableObject` for something like that...

Comment: I probably have made it more complicated than it needs to be, but the filter by it.name == search is not the only way I'm filtering it. for example the full code has several filter checks:


//Add to top of list if the search term exactly matches the name
        set.forEach { if (it.name.toLowerCase() == (search.toLowerCase())) orderedList.add(it) }
        //Add to list if name starts with the exact search term as a standalone word
        set.forEach { if(it.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(search.toLowerCase() + " ")) addToOrderedListIfNotAlreadyAdded(orderedList, it) }


etc

Comment: that sounds a bit ineffective, if I get `addToOrderedListOfNotAlreadyAdded` correctly... you may want to iterate over your set only once and check all filters within the foreach directly... or pass the filters in an ordered list (which should also be taken as the order of the resulting list) and be completely flexible on which filter you want to pass or not... ... I will put some sample code in an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you would have `SearchableObject` as an interface, not a class, as its contract doesn't assume any state. This also allows the implementation classes to derive some other class. So it would be:

```
interface SearchableObject {
    val name: String
}

class Allergy(override var name: String = "Allery name not given") : SearchableObject {
    /* ... */
}
```

As for filtering instances of `Allergy` in the search results, you could use the standard library function [`filterIsInstance<...>()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-is-instance.html):

```
override fun autoSuggest(search: String): List<Allergy> =
    utils.sortObjectsBySearchRelevance(search, allergies).filterIsInstance<Allergy>()
```

To be able to generically filter instances of a certain type, consider defining a generic function with a [`reified` type parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) (which is, in particular, the way to use the type parameter for type checks at runtime):

```
inline fun <reified T : SearchableObject> autoSuggestInstancesOf(search: String): List<T> = 
    utils.sortObjectsBySearchRelevance(search, allergies).filterIsInstance<T>()
```

With the usage: `autoSuggestInstancesOf<Allergy>("...")`. You may also use [`.filter { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html) for filtering the results list by any other criteria, but note that it won't affect the inferred elements type of the returned list (it will still be `List<SearchableObjects>`).

Comment: Filtering by instance on a generic function with `reified` type parameter seems to be what I'm after as a more elegant way of getting the right object type in the returned list.
I'll give that a go now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can set an [upper bound](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#upper-bounds) to the generic type:

```
fun <T : SearchableObject> sortObjectsBySearchRelevance(search: String, set: Set<T>): List<T>
```

This way the generic type `T` is constrained to be a **subtype** of `SearchableObject`, so you can access the `SearchableObject` properties and methods inside your generic function.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't introduce something like a `SearchableObject`, but rather stick to default functions as often as possible, e.g. `filter`. Note also that you should iterate over your `Set` as few times as possible (what about "once"?). Depending on the size of your `Set`, how often you call that search function and how complex your actual search algorithm is, you otherwise slow down the whole search unnecessarily.

Putting your search-functionality in its own function is ok, if want to reuse it.

Now I assume that you usually have a `List` or `Set` of a single type only (if not, you can still use `filterIsInstance<YourType>` to filter for certain types before applying the search).

A possible generic solution could be to add something as follows (if you only want to support `String` you can also replace `C` directly with `String`):

```
/**
 * Returns all entries matching any of the given filters, sorted by the order of the given filters.
 */
fun <C, T> Set<T>.filterAndSortBy(
    propertyToCompare: (T) -> C,
    vararg filters: (C) -> Boolean
): List<T> {
  val indexedFilters = filters.withIndex()
  return asSequence()
      .mapNotNull { entry ->
        val property = propertyToCompare(entry)
        indexedFilters.firstOrNull { (_, filter) -> filter(property) }
                      ?.index?.let { it to entry }
      }
      .sortedBy { it.first }
      .map { it.second }
      .toList()
}
```

and then implement your specific `search`-function as you need it, e.g.:

```
fun <T> Set<T>.search(
    searchString: String,
    propertyToCompare: (T) -> String
) = filterAndSortBy(propertyToCompare,
                    // exact matches first
                    { it == searchString },
                    // exact matches ignoring case second
                    { it.equals(searchString, true) },
                    // third
                    { it.contains(searchString) },
                    // last
                    { it.contains(searchString, true) }
)
```

Finally for all the interested specific objects you can either call that last function directly or supply another extension function, e.g.:

```
// calling it directly
yourSet.search("some value") {
  it.propertyToSearch // when comparing the search string, use this given property
}

// or adding an extension function
fun Set<MyObj>.search(searchString : String) = search(searchString) { it.propertyToSearch }
```

With the implementaton above you can simply call that function on your `Set` directly. If you want to filter and sort some other things, you can still use the `filterAndSortBy`-function instead.

Some sample code:

```
data class MyObj(val name: String) {
  override fun toString() = name
}

val set = sequenceOf("one", "onE", "containing one", "filtered out", "ONE", "ONE!!!")
    .map(::MyObj)
    .toSet()
    .also(::println)

sequenceOf("ONE", "one", "onE")
    .forEach { searchString ->
      set.search(searchString) {
        it.name
      }.run(::println)
    }
```

which then produces an output similar to:

```
[one, onE, containing one, filtered out, ONE, ONE!!!] // the input set
[ONE, one, onE, ONE!!!, containing one] // when searching for: ONE
[one, onE, ONE, containing one, ONE!!!] // when searching for: one
[onE, one, ONE, containing one, ONE!!!] // when searching for: onE
```

Comment: That's great! Much less overhead without multiple iterations over the set, and just the sort of thing I was hoping to get right with this learning project, thank you!